# parsing row element and add style to a href element

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm getting the following HTML table:

```
<tbody>
   <tr role="row" class="odd">
   <td></td>
   <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">Nicolas COPERNIC</a></td>
   <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">dsdsdsds</a></td>
   <td></td>
   <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">2018-06-14 17:41</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="unread even" role="row">
   <td></td>
   <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">Nicolas COPERNIC</a></td>
   <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">aa</a></td>
   <td></td>
   <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">2018-06-14 07:57</a></td></tr> 
</tbody>
```

This table is created thanks to a datatable:

```
$('#datatable-table').DataTable({
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false ,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bSort": false,
                "bAutoWidth" : true,

                ajax: 'Getdata?user='+Glogin,
                    columns: [
                        {   "data":"checkbox"
                        },
                        { "data": "two" },
                        { "data": "three" },
                        { "data": "four" },
                        { "data": "five" },
                        { "data": "six" }
                    ],
                    "aaSorting": [[ 5, "desc" ]],
                    createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
                        console.log("row"+row);
                        console.log("data 8: "+data["read"]);
                        if (data["read"] == "0") {
                            console.dir(row);
                            $(row).addClass("unread");
                        }
                }
            });
```

The function createdRow is getting each row created in my table, and I would like to parse the element $(row) to add on the a href element a specific style.
How can I parse the elements of the row and add this specific style tag to my a href element ?

having in the end:

```
<a id="link" href="detail.jsp" style="color: red">Nicolas COPERNIC</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find `a` on table and add `css` like below.

```js
$('table tr.unread').find('a').css({
  "color": "red"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">Nicolas COPERNIC</a></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">dsdsdsds</a></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">2018-06-14 17:41</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unread even" role="row">
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">Nicolas COPERNIC</a></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">aa</a></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">2018-06-14 07:57</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Alternative is you can use `attr`.

```js
$('table tr.unread td').find('a').attr( "style", "color:red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">Nicolas COPERNIC</a></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">dsdsdsds</a></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">2018-06-14 17:41</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unread even" role="row">
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">Nicolas COPERNIC</a></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">aa</a></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><a id="link" href="detail.jsp">2018-06-14 07:57</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> Note: You can do this after `DataTable` bind.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I would like to update the a href only for the <tr> tags having the class "unread"

Comment: I tried to use $('table tr.unread td').find('a').attr( "style", "color:red"); but also $('#datatable-table tr.unread td').find('a').attr( "style", "color:red"); but no effect

Comment: yes it works now, I had to wait the end of the datatable render "initComplete": function(settings, json) {
                            console.log("datatable ended");
                            $('#datatable-table tr.unread td').find('a').attr( "style", "color:red");
                          }

Comment: I mention it on note :). Happy for you. You got a solution.